# MySql does not work on vs code. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgKhk.jpg)

All the code is correct and can be run in MySQL workbench, but not in vscode.

```
SELECT * FROM order_item_notes;

-- SELECT * FROM  customers 
-- -- Where customer_id=1 
-- ORDER BY first_name;

-- SELECT first_name,
-- last_name,points,
-- ( points + 10 )*100 AS discount_factor
-- FROM customers;

-- SELECT DISTINCT state FROM customers;
```

I have tried using use database;,but it doesn't work

Comment: Show your code that is trying to use the database?

Comment: If you want to connect to a database you need to have an ODBC Driver installed, and you have to call it from in your code so it knows that is the connection method.

Comment: I put this as a comment instead of an answer because I don't understand how it happens. But I encountered a similar issue. The solution was to keep all commented lines before your statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to CREATE the ODBC DSN NAME to connect to the database then you can use this method to call it

```
                    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")                                          
                    Conn.Open "DSN=ODBCDNS"                                                                  
                    SET RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")                                               
                    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM order_item_notes", Conn
```

Also that tool seems okay .. but stop everything and download MS Workbench .. it will make your life easier.  Granted this is ASP Classic code but I believe it might work in VB as well, or at least get you onto the right track.

Comment: Just curious but did you try making a Data Source Name (DSN) and then use the script I provided with DNS="" <-- your DSN in there, and you should be able to get this to work, unless you just gave up and the answer was a waste of time?